# Set rules method parameters in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to validate the username in CodeIgniter using the form_validation library. What I found on the docs was `$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');`. I'm wondering what are the parameters set in the set rules function? What are they, are they really necessary? I tried to look for the explanation somewhere but never found anything. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Did "somewhere" include the Codeigniter userguide?

Comment: Yes it does. The first place was the user guide. I also searched on stackoverflow, blogs and on google. Even youtube videos. But wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: Check [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form#setting-validation-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
```

- First parameter is the name of the respective field .
- Second parameter is the message to be displayed.
- Third parameter is for condition for form validation.